# Нужно включать приложение камера на моем смартфоне

Tags: java, android

Обращение к java программистам: у меня есть java класс, в котором есть метод который должен открывать приложение камеру на моем смартфоне:

```
package com.example.launchcameraplugin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class LoadCameraPlugin extends AppCompatActivity
{

 public void LaunchCameraApp(final ILoadCameraPluginCallback callback)
  {
   callback.LaunchCameraApp();
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

также у меня есть мое Unity приложение, и C# код, который будет вызывать метод в моем java классе... Здесь же я хотел уточнить, рабочий ли этот java код? если абстрагироваться от C# и Unity, этот java код может запустить приложение камеру? Заранее спасибо!

вот java интерфейс для взаимодействия с Unity:

```
 package com.example.launchcameraplugin;

 public interface ILoadCameraPluginCallback
{
   void LaunchCameraApp();
}
```

Задаю я этот вопрос потому что камера запускаться не хочет... Вот я и пытаюсь понять на чей стороне проблема - java или C#...

Comment: Если в классе LoadCameraPlugin только код с примера, то естественно камера работать не будет. 
Но код
'Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);'
'startActivity(intent);' рабочий. Но проблема все равно в java потому что активити и ILoadCameraPluginCallback неправильно используются.

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное за Ваш ответ! то есть мне нужно убрать callback.LaunchCameraApp();?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данной реализации будет достаточно чтобы сразу запустить камеру.

```
public class LoadCameraPlugin extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо Вам, Александр! и получается java интерфейс теперь будет выглядеть так?: public interface ILoadCameraPluginCallback { void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState); } Еще раз огромное спасибо!